# java.sql.SQLException: Out of memory (Needed 1048544 bytes)

Tags: java, mysql

All of sudden my application started throwing this error, I can see the error on MySQL error log too.

it auto resolved. I did some Google trying to find it what really causes this exception.

want to sort it out this error and not happen again.

Comment: This is an error in the MySQL server, and is not related to Java. Your MySQL configuration may be incorrect. If running 32-bit, consider upgrading to 64-bit. Also see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=52272 (Google Search is your friend)

Comment: yeah I did some search I didn't find any solution anywhere, yes using 32-bit because my machine is also 32-bit machine I can't upgrade it to 64-bit as of now..